# matlab find specific VALUES in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, element

How to find out all array element indices equal to several values (>2)

For example, I have an array a=`[1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 2 2 1]`, I want to know the indices of all elements equal to b=`[2 5]`

Remember, I cannot use style like `a==b(1) | a==b(2)` because number of elements in b is arbitrary.

Do I have to use a for loop to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) (as Daniel said just *seconds* before I hit enter...) ;-)

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 2 2 1];
b=[2 5];
c=find(ismember(a,b))
```

Output:

```
c =

    2    5    6    9   10   11
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it more manually, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
c = find(any(bsxfun(@eq, a(:).', b(:)), 1));
```